# User id on production server goes 1, 11, 21, 31,

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, heroku, mysql-workbench

I made Laravel project, and when I register new user on production, he gets in users table id for 10 numbers.. instead (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..) it goes (1, 11, 21, 31, ..)
I deployed project on Heroku and this is weird in my database.
In local numbers go good.

Comment: explain more   ! g

Comment: I read now that ClearDB has auto_increment 10, so I can't change that... Thank you for helping..